# SQL case statement updating incorrect records

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

What I'm trying to do is either assign leads that are older than 180 days a value of 1 or where the `L.Age_Change IS NULL AND L._Stage IS NOT NULL`

The issue I currently have is that in the query below, Leads are updated even when they are not older than 180 days.

Either I'm being really thick or I'm missing something, I can't seem to work out what the issue is:

```
SELECT
U.*,
L.ID AS Lead_ID,
CASE
    WHEN 
        (L.Age_Change < DATEADD(day,-180, GETDATE())) 
        OR (
            L.Age_Change IS NULL 
            AND L._Stage IS NOT NULL
            ) 
        AND (
            L._Stage NOT LIKE '%Not Interested%' 
            OR L._Stage NOT LIKE '%Duplicate%'
            ) 
        AND (
            L.Start_Term NOT LIKE '%September 2019%' 
            OR L.Start_Term NOT LIKE '%September 2020%' 
            OR L.Start_Term NOT LIKE '%September 2021%'
            ) 
    THEN '1'
```

Any guidance on the issue would be greatly appreciated

Comment: your `OR (L.Age_Change IS NULL AND L._Stage IS NOT NULL) ` looks at wrong place

Comment: @tablecloth26 . . . I don't see what your problem statement has to do with  your code.  You code has way more conditions than you describe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to understand the logic when you have no data to play with, but perhaps you want to think about nesting a set of your conditions in to another CASE statement. this way you only access the '1' flag  by actually meeting the first criteria, and then the second criteria. It may also make debugging slightly easier?

```
SELECT
U.*,
L.ID AS Lead_ID,
CASE
WHEN
    ( L.Age_Change < DATEADD(day,-180, GETDATE()) )
        OR
    ( L.Age_Change IS NULL AND L._Stage IS NOT NULL )
        THEN 
            CASE WHEN
                (
                    L._Stage NOT LIKE '%Not Interested%' AND L._Stage NOT LIKE '%Duplicate%'
                ) 
                AND 
                (
                    L.Start_Term NOT LIKE '%September 2019%' AND  L.Start_Term NOT LIKE '%September 2020%' AND L.Start_Term NOT LIKE '%September 2021%'
                )
                    THEN '1'
                ELSE '0'
            END
ELSE '0'
END
```

I've also changed your OR to AND in your logic.

To complete my point about nesting the CASE statements for each stage, here is an alternative to the above:

```
SELECT
U.*,
L.ID AS Lead_ID,
CASE
WHEN
    ( L.Age_Change < DATEADD(day,-180, GETDATE()) )
        OR
    ( L.Age_Change IS NULL AND L._Stage IS NOT NULL )
        THEN 
            CASE
                WHEN
                    L._Stage NOT LIKE '%Not Interested%'
                        AND L._Stage NOT LIKE '%Duplicate%'
                    THEN
                        CASE
                            WHEN
                                L.Start_Term NOT LIKE '%September 2019%'
                                    AND  L.Start_Term NOT LIKE '%September 2020%'
                                    AND L.Start_Term NOT LIKE '%September 2021%'
                                THEN '1'
                            ELSE '0'
                        END
                    ELSE '0'
            END
ELSE '0'
END
```

alternatively, another solution, if possible, may be to add a flag on the base table, instead of doing all the string interpretation. Then you only need to do a CASE on the flag. E.g. when flag = 1 then... But as I say, it's difficult to help too much as I don't know the full logic.

Answer (score 0):

I have update some logic for first `OR` condition and wrap it with first condition and then apply `AND` condition, please try below query, is it you are looking for?

```
SELECT
U.*,
L.ID AS Lead_ID,
CASE WHEN 
    (
        (
            L.Age_Change < DATEADD(day,-180, GETDATE())
        ) 
        OR 
        (
            L.Age_Change IS NULL AND L._Stage IS NOT NULL
        ) 
    )
    AND 
    (
        L._Stage NOT LIKE '%Not Interested%' OR L._Stage NOT LIKE '%Duplicate%'
    ) 
    AND 
    (
        L.Start_Term NOT LIKE '%September 2019%' OR  L.Start_Term NOT LIKE '%September 2020%' OR L.Start_Term NOT LIKE '%September 2021%'
    ) 
THEN '1' 
ELSE '0' 
END
```

Plese test your query as below steps to check output:

```
Test as below steps one by one and check output:

1: L.Age_Change < DATEADD(day,-180, GETDATE())
2: (
            (
                L.Age_Change < DATEADD(day,-180, GETDATE())
            ) 
            OR 
            (
                L.Age_Change IS NULL AND L._Stage IS NOT NULL
            ) 
        )

3: AND  
        (
            L._Stage NOT LIKE '%Not Interested%' OR L._Stage NOT LIKE '%Duplicate%'
        )
and so on....
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer! However, this still does not fix my problem as it still assigns a value of 1 to those that are not older than 180 days

Comment: At first glance my answer look ok as there `AND` conditions still Please check one by one your `AND` statement which one is responsible. If you have plunker then we can help you better

Comment: Still nothing, i dont think its an issue with the AND statements

Comment: read comments on bottom of my answer, go one by one like that and check output